# Using separate() to split date

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this data frame:

```
Source: local data frame [446,604 x 2]

                  date pressure
    1  2014_01_01_0:01      991
    2  2014_01_01_0:02      991
    3  2014_01_01_0:03      991
    4  2014_01_01_0:04      991
    5  2014_01_01_0:05      991
    6  2014_01_01_0:06      991
    7  2014_01_01_0:07      991
    8  2014_01_01_0:08      991
    9  2014_01_01_0:09      991
    10 2014_01_01_0:10      991
    ..             ...      ...
```

I want to separate the date column using `separate()` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, date, into = c("year", "month", "day", "time"), sep="_")
```

But it does not work. I managed to do it using `substr()` and `mutate()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
mutate(
        year = substr(date,  1, 4),
        month = substr(date,  6, 7),
        day = substr(date, 9, 10),
        time = substr(date, 12, 15))
```

**Update:**

It does not work because I have malformed rows. I was able to diagnose using my initial `substr()` method and I found out that I had weird entries in the dataframe:

```
df %>%
  select(date) %>%

  mutate(
    year = substr(date,  1, 4),
    month = substr(date,  6, 7),
    day = substr(date, 9, 10),
    time = substr(date, 12, 15)) %>%

  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(n=n())
```

And this is what I get:

```
Source: local data frame [33 x 2]

   year      n
1  2014 446293
2  4164      9
3  4165     10
4  4166     10
5  4167     10
6  4168     10
7  4169     10
8  4170     10
9  4171     10
10 4172     10
11 4173     10
12 4174     10
13 4175     10
14 4176     10
15 4177     10
16 4178     10
17 4179     10
18 4180     10
19 4181     10
20 4182     10
21 4183     10
22 4184     10
23 4185     10
24 4186     10
25 4187     10
26 4188     10
27 4189     10
28 4190     10
29 4191     10
30 4192     10
31 4193     11
32 4194     10
33 4195      1
```

Would there be a more efficient way to diagnose the structure of the elements of a column and find the malformed lines before doing separate() ?

Comment: This code `separate(df, date, into = c("year", "month", "day", "time"), sep="_") ` as in your question, works nicely. Make sure you have the current version of tidyr.

Comment: agreed with @docendodiscimus - the `separate` is working for me as well. A `dput(head(df))` might help debug, tho.

Comment: You could also try `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(df, 'date', sep="_", type.convert=FALSE)`

Comment: NOTE: if even one of the rows in `date` is malformed, `separate` will not play nicely with the data and toss an error. What error is it producing? If something like `Error: Values ot split into…` then it's a malformed value.

Comment: @hrbrmstr You are right. Date is malformed. I get: `Error: Values not split into 4 pieces at ...`. Would there be an efficient way to diagnose the structure of the elements of a column and find the malformed lines before doing separate() ?

Comment: Use `extra = merge` or `extra = drop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps would be:

1. Try to `separate()` first (no extra)
2. Notice there are malformed rows (errors in console)
3. Use `separate()` with `extra = "drop"`
4. Use `group_by()` and `summarise()` to explore the data and determine which rows to filter out